# My .Net form won't UPDATE to database successfully

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple /adminarea/ for my site. Within this admin area, there are three pages: Default.aspx (new post), Edit.aspx and View.aspx.

Default allows me to INSERT a new record. View allows me to, using the Reader, display database text on page but Edit doesn't (for some unknown reason) want to UPDATE.

**ASPX**

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

            <DIV style="max-width: 1500px; margin: 0px auto;">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Enter selection text: </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center">
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnServerClick="Button1_Click1" />
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="postID" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </DIV>
    </form>
```

Initially, I did wonder whether or not postID was being generated in the HTML, but if you view source it does show the postID.

**My C#**

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=db652255182.db.1and1.com; Initial Catalog=db652255182; User ID=dbo652255182; Password=290Plots$");

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
{
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 * From homepageSelection ORDER BY postID DESC");
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = con;

    string messageInfo = "";
    int postIDVal = 0;

    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        messageInfo += reader["selectionText"].ToString();
        postIDVal = (int)reader["postID"];
    }

    con.Close();

    TextBox1.Text = messageInfo;
    postID.Value = postIDVal.ToString();
}
    }

    protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                             
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update homepageSelection set selectionText=@selectionText where postID=@postID", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@selectionText", TextBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postID", postID.Value);
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();
    }
}
```

I only have one column in my table: homepageSelection: selectionText

I do **NOT** get any error.

I am also aware of SQL Injection (even though .Net has a lot of built in protection for that). For learning purposes I do believe this is okay however.

I am (not that it's important to this question) working a script that removes dangerous content before it is sent.

Answer (score 1):

Page_Load event fires when you click a button and it fires before the Button1_Click1 event. You should add a IsPostBack -statement to your Page_Load event and only load data from database when the page is not posted back.

This should work:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 * From homepageSelection ORDER BY postID DESC");
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = con;

    string messageInfo = "";
    int postIDVal = 0;

    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        messageInfo += reader["selectionText"].ToString();
        postIDVal = (int)reader["postID"];
    }

    con.Close();

    TextBox1.Text = messageInfo;
    postID.Value = postIDVal.ToString();
}
```

Comment: many thanks. This does now save it when you press Submit, however it still refuses to update the database.